# Why doesn't the way I use nowrap work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn CSS and as part of it I am trying to recreate the menu on 
news.ycombinator.com without looking at how it is organized on the actually page.

Here is my css

```
body{
margin:0; 
}

#outerdiv {
height:100%;
border-left: 2px solid #fcfaf4;
border-right: 2px solid #fcfaf4;
background:#fcfaf4;
position: relative;
left: 15%;
width:70%;
}

#menudiv{
background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
height:4%;
width:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#ycimage{
border: 1px solid white;
width="18";
height="18";
padding:1px;
position: relative;
left:2px;
top:2px;
margin:2px;
}

p{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

My html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id ="menudiv">
        <img src="y18.gif" id="ycimage" >
            <p> 
                <b id="companyname" >Hacker News </b>
                |
                new
                |
                comments
                |
                show
            </p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

I have tried to define nowrap property on

element inside div "menudiv"
HOwever, the word Hacker News appears on the new line, after the image. How can I keep it on the same line?

Comment: <p> is a block level element. This effectively inserts a break before it. Nowrap prevents wrapping of whitespace between inline elements. To solve the problem try using a <span> or other inline tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `<p>` is for paragraph and clears both sides of it with a new-line. Remove the `<p>` or set it to be an inline object using [Display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Something along the lines of:

```
p{display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `<span>` tag instead of the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can achieve the way you have tried.

Make the elements display:inline-block.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#outerdiv {
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #fcfaf4;
  border-right: 2px solid #fcfaf4;
  background: #fcfaf4;
  position: relative;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
}
#menudiv {
  background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
  height: 4%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#ycimage {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv">
  <div id="menudiv">
    <img src="y18.gif" id="ycimage">

    <ul>
      <li> <b id="companyname">Hacker News | </b>
      </li>
      <li>new <strong>|</strong>
      </li>
      <li>comments <strong>|</strong>
      </li>
      <li>show</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps